# arc diff including all changes in submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, phabricator, arcanist

I`m using Phabricator and have main project in git and many submodules inside which are other git`s projects. Lets suppose I changed one file in every submodule and I would like to do arc diff on this changes. Does anybody know if there is a possibility to do somehow arc diff on main project that it will create diff with changes in all submodules and then arc land will push changes in every submodule and also update pointers to submodules in main project?